# Area moment of inertia about the y-axis for a triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, moment-of-inertia

I have a triangle which I have divided into two smaller triangles. Now I'd like to compute the area moment of inertia about the y-axis for the blue triangle. I've set the origin in the bottom between the two triangles (the green dot on in the figure).

[image: The blue and the brown triangle. The origin is marked by the green dot]

To compute it, I'll use the following integral:

$\int_{y=0}^{h}{\int_{x=0}^{?}{x^2}} dxdy$

I need help with the limits. I know that they should be limited by the lines along x and y-axis as well as the sloping line, but I don't know how! Are the limits I've put out correct, and if so, what should the limit marked with '?' be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a relation for x and y which holds true along the hypotenuse of the blue triangle.

We have two data points:

at x = (b-a), y = 0
at x = 0, y = h

(taking the green dot as the origin)

the hypotenuse is a line with the equation y = mx + b

Here, b = h when x = 0 and

m = rise / run = (h - 0) / (0 - (b-a))

therefore, m = h / (a - b)

so the equation of the line segment forming the hypotenuse of the blue triangle is:

y = (h * x) / (a - b) + h

Since we are integrating first w.r.t. x, then the upper limit (marked ?)
becomes:

x = (y - h) * (a - b) / h

The other limits are correct as indicated.